# How to create a bar plot with one categorical variable in different years in ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, geom-bar

I have a very large data frame where each row in the first column represents an id with numbers. The other rows have a categorical variable that can be of two types (in this example, A or B), each for a year. Here's a simplified data frame as an example:

```
id  var2017  var2018  var2019
1     A        B         A
2     B        A         A
3     B        A         B
4     A        A         A
5     A        B         B
```

I'd like to create a bar plot that contains the count of each type (A and B) for each year, with the bars being grouped by type.
I am new with R language, so I've tried to create a plot for the years separately, which works fine, as follows:

```
graph <– ggplot(data = example) +
        geom_bar(aes(x = var2017))
```

The problem is I don't know how to put them all together.
How can I create a plot with all the types for each year being in the x axis, and the count in the y axis?
The id doesn't need to be in the output.

Comment: Is the `id` important? For example, do you need to group by `id`, should it appear in the final output?

Comment: No, the id is irrelevant in the plot.

Comment: OK, then the answer from @jon-spring is along the right lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to plot multiple columns in ggplot is to first convert the data to long form, which can be done with `tidyr::gather`. Then you map the column it came from (now stored in the "year" column) to one aesthetic, and the count to another (`geom_bar` does this for you by counting the number of rows).

```
library(tidyverse);  
ggplot(data = example %>%
         gather(year, type, -id)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = year, fill = type), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

(Note, I changed the example to make the different years have different counts. Otherwise it's less clear to see if it's working.)

```
example <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "id  var2017  var2018  var2019
           1       A        B         A
           2       B        A         A
           3       B        A         B
           4       B        A         A     # var2017 A changed to B
           5       A        B         B")
```

Comment: I am getting error `Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "function"` while running your code. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous answer but using `dplyr::count`, `geom_col` and clearer syntax for the pipes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

example %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -id) %>% 
  count(Var, Val) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var, n)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = Val), 
             position = "dodge")
```